# Update substring in XML column SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I want to perform an update on all the rows in an XML column in SQL Server 2008, replacing just a substring in a certain xml node. I'm new to XML DML / XQuery and all that and I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Example of XML in the column I want to update:

```
<d>
  <p n="Richedit01" t="System.String">
    <v>
      &lt;p&gt; &lt;img border="0" alt="Football4" src="/$-1/football4.jpg" /&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
    </v>
  </p>
</d>
```

I want to replace all occurances of the substring 'src="/$-1/' with 'src="/$-1/file/' in all rows.

Tried this but apparently there is no way that I can use the XPath replace function like this:

```
UPDATE Translation
SET ContentData.modify('replace value of (d/p[@t=''System.String'']/v)[1] with (d/p[@t=''System.String'']/v[replace(.,''src="/$-1/'',''src="/$-1/file/'')]) ')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to convert to another datatype that can accept replace (nvarchar(MAX) for example). Use the REPLACE function, and then convert it back to XML

Something like

```
UPDATE Translation SET
ContentData = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(ContentData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '/$-1/','/$-1/file/') AS XML)
```

Comment: Thank you very much James!

It's a little bit more "risky" not knowing in which node the replace occurs, but it works fine for me. Thanx!